# LaTeX Warning: Citation 'author2012' on page 1 undefined on input line 15

Tags: citing

How do you correct an undefined citation? I've clicked the BibTex option several times to let Latex automatically recognize the new references, but this isn't working.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\begin{document} 
\section{Introduction} 
\label{sec:intro} 
\subsection{A} 
Text with \cite{hatcher2008} 
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{bibfile} 
\end{document}
```

**Addendum**: Here's an excerpt from the `.bib` file:

```
@article{hatcher2008curcumin} 
  title={Curcumin: from ancient medicine to current clinical trials}, 
  author={Hatcher, H. and Planalp, R. and Cho, J. and Torti, FM and Torti, SV}, 
  journal={Cellular and Molecular Life Sciences}, 
  volume={65}, 
  number={11}, 
  pages={1631--1652}, 
  year={2008}, 
  publisher={Springer}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}{options}{natbib}
\pagestyle{headings}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}

\input{./title.tex}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}
\subsection 
\subsubsection 
Text with \cite{hatcher2008}
\subsubsection
\subsubsection
\subsubsection
\subsection
\subsubsection
\subsubsection
\subsubsection

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{bibfile}

\end{document}

Comment: You can edit your own questions to add something or correct it. So you don't have to squeeze your working code into a comment without formatting.

Comment: Not sure how to edit so that formatting is kept in tact

Comment: @Keith - I've taken the liberty of stripping down your MWE to something that really focuses on the situation at hand. Please try to compile it (LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX) and see if the problem persists. If the problem persists, check if there's an entry named `hatcher2008` in your bib file. Also, note that `\section` and `\subsection` commands take a mandatory argument; your full MWE has little chance of compiling properly.

Comment: Right above the text input window there should be some formatting controls. The button with the opening and closing brackets it used to mark code which will then be formatted as code block. Even if this is not working, it's easier to reformat the code when it is put in your question that to squeeze it out of the one-liner comment.

Comment: @mico - yes, the commands do have arguments. I've just deleted for purposes of clarity. There is hatcher2008 reference in the bibfile. I have compiled three times with the same result.

Comment: **To the down-voters: Please note that on this site, we usually do not downvote badly written questions if the questionner is a new-comer to this site. And we consider it rude to downvote a question and not to mention the exact reasons in the comments. I've upvoted the question to keep it at 0 score.**

Comment: After compiling, I get warnings, indicating citations undefined and, after BibTex, I get "I found no database files while reading thesis.aux."

Comment: If you strip down LaTeX code too far (e.g., by eliminating the required arguments of `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` commands), you render your code uncompilable. That's why it's better to omit such commands entirely for the purpose of providing an MWE. Please edit your question to list the exact error and/or warning messages you get. Without this information, there's little hope figuring out what exactly is going on. The BibTeX error message you report, "... found no database files while reading thesis.aux", strongly suggests that entry "hatcher2008" is **not** in `bibfile.bib`.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{headings}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}

\input{./title.tex}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}
\subsection 
\subsubsection 
Text with \cite{hatcher2008}

\subsection


\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{bibfile}

\end{document}

Comment: Preamble


% BibTeX Entries
@article{hatcher2008curcumin}
  title={Curcumin: from ancient medicine to current clinical trials},
  author={Hatcher, H. and Planalp, R. and Cho, J. and Torti, FM and Torti, SV},
  journal={Cellular and Molecular Life Sciences},
  volume={65},
  number={11},
  pages={1631--1652},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Springer}

Comment: 3 errors in BibTek and 12 warnings in pdflatex (citations undefined)

Comment: I've copied the contents of your comment, in which you provide an excerpt from your bib file, to the body of the question and have also formatted the entry a bit. There are (at least!) three problems with the entry: (i) a comma is missing after the `key` (`hatcher2008curcumin`); (ii) a closing right curly brace is missing at the end of the entry (after the `publisher` field); and (iii) the entry's `key` (`hatcher2008curcumin`) is not equal to argument of the `\cite` command (`hatcher2008`). Please fix these issues and then recompile.

Comment: % BibTeX Entries
@article{hatcher2008curcumin},
  title={Curcumin: from ancient medicine to current clinical trials},
  author={Hatcher, H. and Planalp, R. and Cho, J. and Torti, FM and Torti, SV},
  journal={Cellular and Molecular Life Sciences},
  volume={65},
  number={11},
  pages={1631--1652},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Springer}
}

Comment: The entry's key is now equal to the \cite command. I've recompiled by pdflatex for the thesis.tex, bibtex for the bibfile, and then twice pdflatex for the tex. file. ? still represent the int-text citations, and the Bibliography page just says "bibliography."

Comment: There should be no closing brace after the key, only a comma: `@article{hatcher2008curcumin, title=...`. Also bibtex generates a log-file (with the ending `.blg`), check it for error messages.