# how to run BibTex on an undefined citation within LaTex

Tags: citing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX Warning: Citation ‘author2012’ on page 1 undefined on input line 15](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78629/latex-warning-citation-author2012-on-page-1-undefined-on-input-line-15)

I am following Andy Roberts' method on creating a bibliography and doing in text citations. 
http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/bibliographies

How do you run BibTex on an undefined citation within LaTex without running BibTex on the entire .bib database file (containing all the references)?

Comment: If your document is called `main.tex`, you have to run `bibtex main`. What's precisely the problem?

Comment: You don't run bibtex on individual citations you pass it the name of the tex file you are processing, it inputs the bbl file that has been written by latex which details the citations needed, it then reads the bibtex file to extract those citations and produces a .bib file with a typeset bibliography  which is then input by latex on the later run

Comment: so once you've created a .tex file and a .bib file, which I have successfully done, in the same directory, how do you link the two to produce a pdf with in text citations and a complete bibliography? Step by step...I am following other expert websites, like the one I've mentioned, and have been unable to do it...

Comment: The link is done with 1. `\bibliography{bibfile}` or `\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}` (with biblatex), which tells latex which database(s) to use, and with 2. `\cite` and `\nocite` commands which tell latex which entries should be pulled from the database(s).

Comment: @ulrike, I have made sure those are complete. Now, do you perform the pdflatex, then bibtek, then pdflatex twice on BOTH the .tex and .bib files, or just one, or how should you handle these functions as it relates to the two files? I think this is what is confusing me.

Comment: Assuming that your tex-file is called `main.tex` then you should call bibtex on `main.aux` or simply on `main`. When using `biblatex` and `biber` (which is highly recommended) you should run `biber` on `main.bcf` or again simply `main`.